# (Laravel) Form validation not returning with old input

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3. I have a form which is not filling the fields with old input when validation fails. The form looks like this:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'my.route', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => true]) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) }}
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {{ Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'hello world' ,'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('description', 'Description', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) }}
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {{ Form::textarea('description', null, ['placeholder' => 'hello world', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
        <span>some sub-text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('date', 'Date', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) }}
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {{ Form::text('date', null, ['placeholder' => 'hello world', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
</div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I am processing the information like this:

```
    public function store(ItemRequest $request, ImageMagick $imageMagick)
    {
        $item = new Item;
        $item->name = $request->name;
        $item->description = $request->description;
        $item->date = $request->date;

        $item->save();
        return redirect()->route('some.other.route');
    }
```

I am doing my validation in my own form request file "ItemRequest" which looks like this:

```
class ItemRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
        'description' => 'required|min:50',
        'date' => 'required'
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        if ($this->isMethod('post')) {
            return $this->createRules();
        }

        return $this->updateRules();
    }

    public function createRules()
    {
        return self::$rules;
    }

    public function updateRules()
    {
        return array_merge(
            self::$rules,
            $this->otherRules()
        );
    }

    public function otherRules()
    {
       return ['age' => "required"];
    }
}
```

I think the problem lies in ItemRequest. I have tried adding ->withInput() to my return in the store method but the old inputs are still not being retained.

```
  return redirect()->route('some.other.route')->withInput();
```

But it did not make a change.

EDIT: I was clearing the old input when the page refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `value="{{ Input::old('Code')}}"` in your input field area. So in you description text area, you can use,

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('description', 'Description', ['class' => 'control-label col-md-3']) }}
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {{ Form::textarea('description', null, ['placeholder' => 'hello world', 'class' => 'form-control','value'=>'Input::old('description')']) }}
        <span>some sub-text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is still not working. I've tried dumping the old value and it is empty.